# Rating value did not appear in my firebase database

Tags: java, android

I only can save the name but not the rating value as shown in the picture below:-

[image]

My rating coding. For your information, the tuitionName is in the spinner type while the tuitionRating is in the rating bar type. I got an error on getSelectedItem for by tuitionRating... What should I put for ratingBar?

```
private void createRating()
{
    String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String tuitionname = mTuitionName.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    String tuitionrating = mRatingBar.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

    Rates rates = new Rates(uid, tuitionname, tuitionrating);
    mTuitionRates.child("Rates").child(uid).setValue(rates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
        {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                //Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Data has been added successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(RatingActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Instead of this:

```
String tuitionrating = mRatingBar.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
```

Use this:

```
String tuitionrating = String.valueOf(mRatingBar.getRating());
```

Try it. Hope it works.

Comment: How about if im using this one, "float tuitionrating = mRatingBar.getRating();" ???

Comment: `float tuitionrating = mRatingBar.getRating();` This comes in float and `String.valueOf()` converts to string.

Comment: Okay sir, I understand. Now by stepsize = 1. If I want the rating can be 1.3 or mybe 1.7. How should it be?

Comment: For float value: try this: `String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(mRatingBar.getRating()));`